# How to compare fitted survival model with covariates vs. Kaplan-Meier?

Tags: survival, model-comparison, population, kaplan-meier, model-checking

How would one ideally compare fitted survival models with covariates vs. a Kaplan-Meier with a goal of getting an idea of whether the survival model describes the data well.

E.g. in an example like this, you might get the impression that an intercept-only exponential model might be okay:

```
set.seed(1234)
sim <- tibble(patient=1:100, cov=0.66*log(seq(0.1, 1.09, 0.01))) %>%
  mutate(x = rweibull(n=100, shape=0.7, scale=exp(0.5+cov)),
         c = 2-seq(0, 1.98, 0.02),
         time = pmin(x,c),
         event= 1L*(x<=c)) 


survfit1 <- survreg(Surv(time=time, event=event) ~ 1, dist="exponential", data=sim)

plot(survfit(Surv(time=time, event=event) ~ 1, data=sim))

curve(1-pexp(q=x, rate=exp(survfit1$coefficients[1])), 0, 2, col="red", add=T)
```

[image]

However, once there's covariates and esp. once they correlate with duration of follow-up (shift in population over time), it kind of feels like one ought to take that into account.

Should I predict a survival curve for each patient and then average them, with each patient patient contributing until their censoring time?! I'm trying to figure this out and had not found the answer (perhaps looking in the wrong places?).

Comment: not sure but might the continuous ranked probability score $CRPS(F_i,y)=\int_\mathbb{R} ( F_i(x) - \mathbb{1}(x \ge y) ) ^2 dx$ be an option if you have the observations y and the (cumulative) probability predictions F_i. Then you could compute the expectation over y and whichever model i has a lower crps, is better.

Answer (score 8):

You can calculate the residuals from the accelerated failure time model fitted by `survreg()` and compare them with the assumed distribution. You will need to account for the fact that residuals for censored event times are also censored. Hence, you typically compare the Kaplan-Meier estimate of the residuals with the survival function of the assumed distribution. [Here are examples of this procedure](https://www.drizopoulos.com/courses/emc/basic_surivival_analysis_in_r#residuals).

Comment: Question: can you see the Kaplan Meier estimator and the fitted survival model to the observations via the continuous ranked probability score? (Maybe ignoring censoring for a second). Is this a valid route? How would that differ from the residual approach ? How does it exactly work?

Answer (score 5):

Targeted goodness of fit assessment as Dimitris has stated is usually preferred.  Another example is [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/psmcase).

When there are only one or two covariates you can compare model estimates of survival probabilities at fixed times when overlapping moving windows of corresponding Kaplan-Meier estimates, with smoothing of the K-M estimates from each window.  This is shown [here](https://hbiostat.org/rflow/analysis#fig-km).

In terms of comparing non-covariate-adjusted K-M estimates with model-based estimates, you can get a predicted survival curve for each person, and average these curves.  You don't need to do any kind of subsetting with regard to censoring.

In the case where one is worried about the fit of one categorical predictor in a Cox model, such as treatment, and you think the fit is OK for all the other covariates, you can show estimated survival curves for each level of the categorical predictor, adjusting all the other covariates to constants such as medians and modes.  Then do the same but this time stratify on the categorical predictor instead of modeling it as a covariate.  This is "adjusted K-M curves" as shown [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/cox#fig-cox-cabg-adj).

A better approach is to specify a Bayesian model that allows for departures from assumptions by adding more parameters, but putting priors on those added parameters to tilt them towards what you hope is true.  For example you could have departures from proportional hazards that have a skeptical prior to reduce overfitting when the number of events is not large.  The [Stan survival analysis system](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.09633.pdf) is state-of-the-art.